# Create a program that copies all the environment variable into a new char** buffer in lower case and prints them

Tags: c, pointers, environment-variables, segmentation-fault

I got a task (for practising c) to copy envp into a new char** buffer in lower case and print them.
I wrote a program that for some reason keeps giving me segmentation fault.

```
#include <ctype.h> /* tolower() */
#include <stdlib.h> /* malloc() */
#include <stdio.h> /* printf() */

extern char **environ;

int main()
{
        int i = 0;
        char **envp = (char **) malloc(sizeof(environ));
        char **envp_cpy = envp;
        char *temp;
        for(i = 0; environ[i] != NULL; i++)
        {
                temp = environ[i];
                while(*temp != '\0')
                {
                        **envp_cpy = tolower(*temp);
                        *envp_cpy++;
                        *temp++;
                }
                *envp_cpy++;
        }
        for (i = 0; envp[i] != NULL; i++)
        {
                printf("%s\n",envp[i]);
        }
        free(envp);
        return 0;

}
```

Comment: If you use the envp argument you should not overwrite (with malloc) or free it.

Comment: I am not able to compile your code as is with envp beng redeclared.  The minimal fix for that is to leave out the arguments.  Also, I need to add `extern char **environ;`.

Comment: Missing includes (ctype, stdio. stdlib)

Comment: What system are you using?  I needed to also an `extern` declaration for `environ`.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 22.04.3

Comment: If you want to demonstrate that the copy worked why do you print out `envp` instead of `envp_copy`?

Comment: envp and envp_copy are pointing both to the same memory addresses, I ma using the copy to iterate through the addresses and lower case the whole thing

Comment: `tolower()` doesn't lowercase a string just a character.  Don't revise the code for that though.   Did I answer your question below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`char **envp = (char **) malloc(sizeof(environ))` allocates 8 bytes on my system which is the size of a pointer.  This means `**envp_cpy = tolower(*temp);` is a buffer overflow and it segfaults for me when`*envp_cpy` is NULL.

Here is how I would write it:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *str_tolower(const char *s) {
    size_t n = strlen(s) + 1;
    char *s2 = malloc(n);
    if(!s2) return NULL;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        s2[i] = tolower(s[i]);
    return s2;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp) {
    char **envp_copy = NULL;
    for(int i = 0;; i++) {
        char **tmp = realloc(envp_copy, (i+1) * sizeof *tmp);
        if(!tmp) {
            fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed\n");
            goto err;
        }
        envp_copy = tmp;
        if(!envp[i]) {
            envp_copy[i] = NULL;
            break;
        }
        envp_copy[i] = str_tolower(envp[i]);
        if(!envp_copy[i]) {
            fprintf(stderr, "str_tolower failed\n");
            goto err;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; envp_copy[i]; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", envp_copy[i]);
        free(envp_copy[i]);
    }
    free(envp_copy);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

err:
    if(envp_copy)
        for(int i = 0; envp_copy[i]; i++)
            free(envp_copy[i]);
    free(envp_copy);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

The operating system will free allocated memory on exit so you don't really need the `free()` calls in this program.  I added it to emphasize that you take on that obligation both in the normal and failure cases in production code.

Comment: Do you have an idea for implementation? 
I don't have any more ideas to be honest and I'll be glad to get some help.

Comment: Yeah, you need to either count and allocate the right sized array or `realloc()` as you iterate through the source.

Comment: thanks, I'll try that and get back to you

Comment: It works except that it doesn't work for me with the lower case function I created.
I know that it has no point but that's what I've been asked to do.

Comment: Let me revise the answer with that code.  Give me a sec.

Comment: Might have been because you printed `envp[i]` and I forgot to change it to `envp_copy[i]`.

Comment: Yeah, probably. Thank you very much.